# Change the map of Veins

Tags: omnet++

I want to change the default map of Veins. I made the map extraction steps from OpenStreetMap and I got the following files:

lyon.net.xml , lyon.poly.xml ,  lyon.rou.xml  , lyon.sumo.cfg~   ,  typemap.xml , lyon.osm , lyon.rou.alt.xml , lyon.sumo.cfg  trips.trips.xml

what do I need to change in veins or in this statement:

/c/Users/user/src/veins-3.0/sumo-launchd.py -vv -c /c/Users/user/src/sumo-0.21.0/bin/sumo.exe

so that I can simulate the veins exemlpe with the new map? Do I have to change something in sumo-launchd.py?

Answer (score 1):

Veins comes with a small daemon to make running coupled simulations easier. This daemon, `sumo-launchd.py`, is designed to run in the background, listening for incoming requests. On each incoming connection, it receives the simulation setup in XML format, then launches a separate instance of SUMO and proxies requests between OMNeT++ and SUMO.

OMNeT++ reads this XML from the file configured in [`manager.launchConfig`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4a2/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd.ned#L52). By convention the file has an extension of `.launchd.xml`, but any can be used.

I would suggest to copy, then adapt, then modify the `.launchd.xml` file that comes with the Veins example to match the files that your simulation uses.